# Error in max(.) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument when using dplyr dbplyr and bigrquery

Tags: r, dbplyr, bigrquery

I'm running some very simple `dplyr` code on a bigquery table using `dbplyr`

```
transactions %>% select(date) %>% max(.)
```

Produces the error

> Error in max(.) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

I have checked that

- The table I am querying queries as expected (it does - other dplyr operations work)
- I can filter for possible NAs, but no records are removed (no NAs)

Also note, similar code on a similar data.frame seems to work, e.g.

```
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length) %>% max
# [1] 7.9
```

Comment: Have you check the output of `str(transactions)` ?

Comment: What does `transactions %>% select(date) %>% print(.)` look like? Does it produce an error or does it look quirky?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried max(unlist(.))?

Take for example:

```
my.list = list(1,2,3,4)
# This produces an error
max(my.list)
# This produces 4
max(unlist(my.list))
```

You could also try do.call(max,my.list).

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the work `dbplyr` does is translate `dplyr` commands into database code (in your case bigquery). The cost of this is that not all R commands can be translated. In general you need to follow standard `dplyr` syntax for a translation to be defined.

So while

```
transactions %>% select(date) %>% max(.)
```

works with an R data frame. There is probably no translation for `max(.)` defined in the context you have used it.

However the following should work because it follows standard `dplyr` syntax:

```
transactions %>% select(date) %>% summarise(max_date = max(date))
```

Hence `dbplyr` can translate it into database code.

To check the underlying database query that `dbplyr` has translated you can use the command `show_query()`. For example:

```
transactions %>% select(date) %>% summarise(max_date = max(date) %>% show_query()
```